# Can I Open a web application,which is desingned in Visual Studio,in Composite C1 CMS,If I can,how to Use this CMS to edit or update the Content?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, c1-cms

Can I Open a web application, which is designed in Visual Studio, in [Composite C1 CMS](http://www.composite.net)? If I can, how to use this CMS to edit or update the Content?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think we can use the Composite c1 CMS to manage the Contents in a custom web application which you have designed.

You have left with one option only i.e., converting every user controls of web application in Composite C1